# joint venture agreements OR joint-venture agreements

Tags: punctuation

Are there any issues hyphenating "joint venture" as a modifier? e.g., "joint-venture agreements" or "joint venture agreements"?

Comment: The hyphen helps, so may be used, though not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, *joint-venture agreement* is a familiar enough term that even if no hyphen is used, anyone reading about such an agreement is unlikely to be in any doubt about the writer's intention.

Logically, however, the hyphen *is* needed. Without the hyphen, the format of the expression gives no indication that 'joint venture' is an adjectival phrase. A naive reader might therefore suppose that the entity being described is a 'venture agreement'.

To sum up: using a hyphen disambiguates the term.

Answer (score 1):

Joint venture : two words, an adjective followed by a noun.

> Joint-venture agreements

Since "joint-venture" modifies the noun "agreement," the hyphenated words are considered to be ONE adjective.